# Count how many times a series of strings appears in a list - Python

Tags: python, string, count, tuples

I'm working on Python (and I'm very new to it) and I have several tuples of the type

```
A = ('T-ha', 'T-he',  'PRE-ma')
B = ('T-ha', 'M-ha',  'PRE-ma')
```

and I want to count how many times several strings appear in each tuple and, in case this number is higher than 1, delete the tuple.

The strings that I want to test are something like `T`, `PRE` and `M`.

In this case, I would delete the first tuple and keep the second.

I know that, with `str.count(str2)`, I can check if an individual of those strings is present but I need to check all of them at the same time (and once the count is higher than 1, stop the counting and delete the tuple).

Any ideas?

Thankss in advance!

Comment: What language are you working in? I assume it's Python, but you should edit your tags to include it so people know what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, it's Python. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this might do the trick:

```
search = ['T', 'PRE', 'M']

for i in search: 
    if ''.join(B).count(i) > 1: 
        del B
```

Put the strings you want to test for into a list, temporarily convert your tuple into a single string and count occurrences of the items on your searchlist. If the count comes out > 1 delete the tuple.